# HttpWebRequest fails after third call

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

here's my method:

```
private static void UpdatePref(List<EmailPrefer> prefList)
{
    if(prefList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (EmailPref pref in prefList)
        {
            UpdateEmailRequest updateRequest = new UpdateEmailRequest(pref.ID.ToString(), pref.Email, pref.ListID.ToString());
            UpdateEmailResponse updateResponse =(UpdateEmailResponse) updateRequest.SendRequest();

            if (updateResponse.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Update Succsesful.  ListID:{0}  Email:{2}  ID:{1}", pref.ListID, pref.Email, pref.ID));
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Update Unsuccessful.  ListID:{0}  Email:{2}  ID:{1}\n", pref.ListID, pref.Email, pref.ID));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error:{0}", updateResponse.ErrorMessage));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Updates Complete.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Procses ended.  No records found to update");
}
```

the list has around 84 valid records that it's looping through and sending an API request for.  But it stops on the 3rd API call and only processes 2 out of the 84 records.  When I debug to see what's happening, I only see that it stops here in my SendRequest method without spitting out any error.  It's stops at the GetRequestStream and when I step to that and try to keep stepping, it just stops and my application stops running without any error!

```
HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(requestURI, data.Length);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 30000;

// Send the Request
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

wtf?  Eventually if I let it keep running I do get the error "The Operation Has Timed Out".  But then why did the first 2 calls go through and this one timed out?  I don't get it.

Also, a second question.  Is it inefficient to have it create a new object inside my foreach for sending and receiving?  But that's how I stubbed out those classes and required that an email, ListID and so forth be a requirement to send that type of API call.  I just didn't know if it's fine or not efficient to create a new instance through each iteration in the foreach.  Might be common but just felt weird and inefficient to me.

Comment: hmm, I had to add request.Abort();  Does that sort of close it or something?

Comment: actually I didn't even need that.  I needed to close the response each time with response.Close();  I guess when you're doing bulk calls you need to close it so that the next quick call can use the object again and it doesn't get tied up?

Comment: so it's said it's not good to use response.Close.  I am lost here.  Should I be flushing instead?  I don't get this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It seems you answered your own question already in the comments.

I don't have personal experience with this, but it seems you need to call close on the HTTP web request after you've fetched the response.  There's a limit of 2 on the number of open connections and the connection isn't freed until you Close().  See http://blogs.msdn.com/feroze_daud/archive/2004/01/21/61400.aspx, which gives the following code to demonstrate the symptoms you're seeing.

```
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
       HttpWebRequest r = WebRequest.Create(“http://www.microsoft.com“) as HttpWebRequest;
       HttpWebResponse w = r.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up also just wrapping it in a using statement to close it.  I'll check out that link.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for it timing out is that the server you're talking to is throttling you.  You might try inserting a delay (a second, maybe?) after each update.

Assuming that `UpdateEmailRequest` and `UpdateEmailResponse` are somehow derived from `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` respectively, it's not particularly inefficient to create the requests the way you're doing it.  That's pretty standard.  However, note that `WebResponse` is `IDisposable`, meaning that it probably allocates unmanaged resources, and you should dispose of it--either by calling the `Dispose` method.  Something like this:

```
UpdateEmailResponse updateResponse =(UpdateEmailResponse) updateRequest.SendRequest();
try
{
    if (updateResponse.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Update Succsesful.  ListID:{0}  Email:{2}  ID:{1}", pref.ListID, pref.Email, pref.ID));
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine( String.Format("Update Unsuccessful.  ListID:{0}  Email:{2}  ID:{1}\n", pref.ListID, pref.Email, pref.ID));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error:{0}", updateResponse.ErrorMessage));
}
finally
{
    updateResponse.Dispose();
}
```

I guess it's possible that not disposing of the response objects keeps an open connection to the server, and the server is timing out because you have too many open connections.